# Calculation of the error for the weighted arithmetic mean

Tags: data-analysis

I am trying to derive the error for the weighted arithmetic mean
$$
\langle A \rangle=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{A_i}{\sigma_{A_i}^2}}{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sigma_{A_i}^2}}.
$$
of a Data-Set $A_i$ with the errors $\sigma_{A_i}$.

With the gaußian propagation of uncertainty for a function $f(x_1,...,x_N)$
$$
\sigma_f=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\right)^2\sigma_{x_j}^2}\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)
$$
we get (here: $f\equiv\langle A \rangle$, $x_i\equiv A_i$) ($\sigma_i:=\sigma_{A_i}$, sums and products go from 1 to N):
$$
\sigma_{\langle A \rangle}\stackrel{(1)}{=}\sqrt{\sum_j\left(\frac{1}{\sigma_j\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\sum_j\frac{1}{\sigma_j^2\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}}\stackrel{(2)}{=}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}}.
$$
This is the correct answer. So the first root must be equal to 1 $\forall \{\sigma_i|i=1,...,N\}$ (for all "error lists")(I have computed this in Python and it is correct!). I managed to bring the radicand on one denominator, but I still don't get to the conclusion I want:
$$
\sum_j\frac{1}{\sigma_j^2\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}
    =\frac{1}{\prod_k \left( \sigma_k^2 \sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)}
    \sum_j \frac{\prod_k \left( \sigma_k^2 \sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)}{\sigma_j^2\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}
    =\frac{\sum_j \prod_{k\neq j} \left(\sigma_k^2 \sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2} \right)}
    {\prod_k \left( \sigma_k^2 \sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)}
    \stackrel{?}{=}1.\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (2)
$$
**Question: How do I show that Equation (2) is equal to 1?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the answer now. I overcomplicated it by trying to put it on one denominator.
$$
\sum_j\frac{1}{\sigma_j^2\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}}=\sum_j\frac{1}{\sigma_j^2}\left(\sum_i \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2}\right)^{-1}=1
$$